# Return record only if the condition in the query matches | MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, aggregation

Below is my query

```
db.getCollection('ledgers').aggregate(
[              
    {
       "$project":{
                    "name":1,
                    "generated":1 
                    timeSpend:{
                                 $divide : 
                                 [{
                                    $subtract: 
                                     ["$generated",new Date()]
                                   }, 3600000
                                 ]
                               }
                   }
    }
])
```

**generated** -- is the column which holds the ISO date value (**ISODate("2001-04-11T22:12:01.249Z")**)

Here I'm trying to find the number of hours by substracting with the current date. I also want to add one filter that if the **timeSpend** is greater than 14 hours only those records should return.

I don't want to return the entire record whose timeSpend value is less than 14 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `$match` stage to filter the results where `timeSpend > 14`

If your dates are in the past, the `$subtract` should be reversed.
`timeSpend  = new Date() - $generated`

```
[
  {
    "$project": {
      "name": 1,
      "generated": 1,
      "timeSpend": {
        $divide: [
          {
            $subtract: [
              new Date(),
              "$generated"
            ]
          },
          3600000
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      timeSpend: {
        $gt: 14
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mUdy6Iwpk_W)